# isometric perspective in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, 3d, isometric

How can I get a perfect isometric perspective in Silverlight ?

I want to create a 3D environment in Silverlight, which has to be in Isometric perspective.
If I use the planeprojection, I can make a grid resemble the Isometric perspective, but it is not a perfect Isometric perspective, as the gridcells are not equal.

http://uwconcept.be/projects/uwconceptcity/grid_base_1.jpg

People will have to be able to "scroll" along the grid; i.e. move forward, backward, left and right on it. You can see it as flying over the grid, but keeping the correct Isometric perspective at all times. Rotating will not be implemented ( in a first version ). And even if it would be implemented, the rotating would be exactly 90 degrees, as to keep the Isometric perspective.

**Edit:** I also noticed that the "normal" isometric x,y,z Coordinates do not apply when i tried to reproduce the perspective in Silverlight. The "normal" transformations are shown in the following Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wikipedia_isometric_cube_3.jpg

Comment: Wow, great question.  Is the camera position going to be static?

Comment: Good remark, @foson, i updated my Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can wait for SL5 to be released,  it is supposed to have a 3D API.   Silverlight 5 beta was announced for release in the 1st half of 2011 (should be any day now). The final release is planned for the end of 2011.

I assume the SL API should be similar to WPF's 3D API.  From my casual understanding, you can create an isometric projection with the correct angling of an OrthographicCamera (which is included in WPF).

Comment: Okay I'll put this on hold then. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

The built in 3d projection support in SL4 is probably not adequate for you needs. It is very limited and is generally only useful for rotating simple objects.

But you have two other options:

- Use a 3D engine and set it to render in isometric 3D. I think [Balder](http://balder.codeplex.com/) can do this for instance, but probably not out of the box.
- Fake the isometric 3D by drawing pre-rendered sprites at the correct position. I suppose you want your "game world" to be built up of tiles (squares) that are rotated to fit the isometric 3D perspective. If you pre render all the tiles in the correct angle then you can calculate where to place them and get the desired effect. Using this option you won't get any depth in the display, tiles farther away will be the same size as those nearby, but apart from that it is not too hard.

I tried to do that latter myself once, just for fun. It was quite easy to draw a flat landscape, but it gets tougher once you want to support slopes.

If you end up doing this, then I hope you open source the project, for there is so much fun you can do with isometric 3d :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, and yes I will open source it once I get a good basic layer. Though I do worry about the graphics performance when having to place i.e. 10,000 tiles positioned by a calculation.

Comment: 10.000 tiles? That sounds excessive, but I don't know what you are trying to make. The calculations will have to be done even if you have a proper ISO-3d engine. The difference is that you can't see it. SL doesn't support much hardware acceleration so most of the computations will have to be done by the CPU no matter what you do.

Comment: I want to create a robust platform from the beginning, baring in mind that the grid might eventually grow to 100x100 tiles. On the screenshot, there was only one calculation, i created a grid with *n by n* fields, and that grid was then transformed with a planeprojection to the "Isometric" perspective